# Installing and Using Node JS in My Project

Tags: node.js, cordova

Im very very new in NodeJS

I want to ask about installing and using it in my Project..

I've installed nodejs in my Windows, but I have no idea how to make it works in my **Cordova/Phonegap Project**. I want to install this module in my project [node-gcm](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm). it said I just have to execute **npm install node-gcm --save** but I dont know where should I execute that command so I tried executed it on my project root (/www). After that I tried the example application code to use it but It said that **require is not defined**. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn `nodejs` properly to use in your project. I would recommend the below site could be a good starting point for you which covers all the basics.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because, when you look at the `package.json` file of the `node-gcm` package, you will notice the dependencies mentioned as,

[image]

If you are a windows user, you need to get into your `node_modules` directory by giving `cd node_modules` command in your command line and then just issue this command `npm install` which will install all the required packages.

Hope this helps!.